# Creating the multiple Audio Tag inside the div and play MP3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-audio

I am having ajax data where I am getting base64 Mp3 data from my DB, on success I am able to play the mp3 using audio tag, but when I get more than one base64 data from DB, I have to crate multiple audio tags and I have to link base64 to each audio tags. Below is my code:

```
 ///Html
<div id="container">
 <audio id="audio"  controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
</div>

///Ajax call getting the base64 from DB and adding has source to audio tag
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url:  'xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx',
    data: xxxxxx,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data[0].Base64 != null) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            alert(key + ": " + value);
            $("#audio").html("<source src=\"data:audio/Mp3;base64," + value.Base64 + "\"/>"); });
        } else {
            alert("No Data")
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `each()` loop, you can create new DOM objects for every entry and append it to your `#container`:

```
var audio = $('<audio><source src="data:audio/Mp3;base64,' + value.Base64 + '"/>');
$("#container").append(audio);
```

Comment: thx,its worked,i did lit bit change in it " var audio = $('<audio id="audio"controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>');
                    audio.html("<source src=\"data:audio/Mp3;base64," + value.Base64 + "\"/>")"

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this type of structure:

```js
///Ajax call getting the base64 from DB and adding has source to audio tag
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url:  'xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx',
    data: xxxxxx,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data[0].Base64 != null) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            alert(key + ": " + value);
            $("#container").append("<audio source src=\"data:audio/Mp3;base64," + value.Base64 + " controls='controls' autobuffer='autobuffer' autoplay='autoplay'></audio>"); });
        } else {
            alert("No Data")
        }
    }
 });
```

```html
 ///Html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this....

```
<div id="boxes">
    <li id="nyan" class="audioclick"><audio src="song.mp3"/></li>
    <li id="duck" class="audioclick"><audio src="duck.mp3"/></li>
    <li id="duck" class="audioclick"><audio src="cat.mp3"/></li>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('#boxes').on('click','audioclick',function(){
        var $eq = $(this).eq(),
            audio = $('audio').get($eq);

        if (audio.paused){
            audio.play();
        } else {
            audio.pause();
        }
    });
});
```